# CloudSim - Cpu Utilization

Tags: cloudsim

Can anyone explain the real difference between these two methods

**vm.getTotalUtilizationOfCpu(CloudSim.clock());**

and

**cloudlet.getUtilizationOfCpu(CloudSim.clock());**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's the difference.

*1) vm.getTotalUtilizationOfCpu(CloudSim.clock());*

getTotalUtilizationOfCpu is the **method of class vm.**
You can c**all it by instance of vm class**

If you look at the implementation of this method in [source code](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/blob/master/modules/cloudsim/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/CloudletScheduler.java#L194).

```
public abstract double getTotalUtilizationOfCpu(double time);

    /**
     * Gets the current requested mips.
     * 
     * @return the current mips
     */
```

It returns the **cpu utilization in form of mips**

*2) cloudlet.getUtilizationOfCpu(CloudSim.clock());*

getTotalUtilizationOfCpu is the **method of class cloudlet.**
You can **call it by instance of cloudlet class**

if you look at the implementation of this method in [source code](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/blob/master/modules/cloudsim/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/Cloudlet.java#L1613).

```
/**
     * Gets the utilization percentage of cpu.
     *
     * @param time the time
     * @return the utilization of cpu
     */
    public double getUtilizationOfCpu(final double time) {
        return getUtilizationModelCpu().getUtilization(time);
    }
```

It returns the **cpu utilization in form of percentage (between 0 to 1)**